# STM32 Virtual COM Port device not work then linux start

Tags: linux, stm32

I have a device(STM32 Virtual COM Port).In Linux it is detected normally /dev/ttyACM0. After starting the operating system, I do not receive data from the device. If turn it off and back on it works fine. The problem appears only when I reboot the operating system. Can you tell me how to make it work after restarting the OS.
Its my dmesg

```
[    1.077892] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.228321] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    1.228335] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.228341] usb 1-5: Product: STM32 Virtual COM Port  
[    1.228345] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[    1.228349] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 5CF862553730
```

Comment: What is the STM32 device in question? A well known dev board or a custom device? What is the exact model of the uC?

Comment: Its custom device. Do you think this is the problem? The device works normally if it is disconnected and reconnected.

Comment: The connection of the pull-up resistor on the D+ line and the Vbus detection may affect it. Some models have internal pull-up resistors and automatic Vbus detection. Also, being self-powered or bus-powered may also be important. Please provide more details about the setup/configuration.